# Byte allocation in struct containing struct within C

Tags: c, memory-management, struct

I have the following structs in a C program.

```
typedef struct
{
  unsigned char msg_id : 8;
  unsigned char msg_num : 8;
} Message_Header_Type;
typedef struct
{
  Message_Header_Type header;
  int msg[32];
} Raw_Message_Type;
```

What I'm seeing is that the header in the Raw_Message_Type is taking up 4 bytes but I only want it to take only 2.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If you pack the structure, you may be able to get `Message_Header_Type` down to 2 bytes -- but in `Raw_Message_Type`, `header` may still be followed by 2 bytes of padding so that the `int` array can be aligned on a 4-byte boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Message_Header_type` inside of `Raw_Message_Type` is still taking 2 bytes as you would expect, but the compiler is padding the structure for alignment reasons, so your `Raw_Message_Type` is 132 bytes long instead of the 130 bytes you expected.  This is probably because 32-bit aligned accesses are more efficient on your processor.

If you are using gcc, you can tell the compiler to align on 2-byte boundaries instead of the 4-byte boundaries that it is using by using `#pragma pack`.

```
typedef struct
{
  unsigned char msg_id : 8;
  unsigned char msg_num : 8;
} Message_Header_Type;
#pragma pack(push, 2) // save current alignment and set to 2-byte boundaries
typedef struct
{
  Message_Header_Type header;
  int msg[32];
} Raw_Message_Type;
#pragma pack(pop) // restore the previous alignment
```

Special packing like this is often necessary when using fixed-size structures in files, but be aware that there may be a (light) performance penalty for using a different packing than what the processor prefers.  In this specific case, your 32 msg[] `int`s are now all 2 bytes off from the preferred alignment for your platform.

Comment: This worked.  I am using Visual Studio so the "__attribute__" in other answers did not compile.  But, I'm sure they will help others.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is **struct packing**, which is platform and compiler dependent, the details are not specified in the C standard.

With GCC, on a 32-bit platform, you could do the following to get a struct of size 2:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__))
{
    unsigned char msg_id;
    unsigned char msg_num;
} Message_Header_Type;
```

From the GCC documentation:

> `packed`
>       This attribute, attached to an enum, struct, or union type definition, specified that the minimum required memory be used to represent the type.

Comment: I happen to like your approach more than mine, so I'm upvoting.

Comment: @JoshSanford Good to know about the pragma. +1

Answer (score 1):

C implementations are free to insert padding into `struct` layouts between members, at the end, or both.  It is common for them to do so for alignment purposes.  It is also common for compilers to provide a mechanism to influence or override the padding, but details are necessarily implementation-specific.

With GCC, for example, you could apply the `packed` attribute to both your `structs`:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__))
{
  unsigned char msg_id : 8;
  unsigned char msg_num : 8;
} Message_Header_Type;

typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__))
{
  Message_Header_Type header;
  int msg[32];
} Raw_Message_Type;
```

Some other implementations borrow GCC's approach; some use `pragma`s for the same purpose; and some provide other mechanisms.  You'll need to check your compiler's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Structure objects are not guaranteed the size of the sum of bits used in member bit fields. This is due to padding.

In your case though `Raw_Message_Type` has another member `int msg[32];`. It seems logical to use two more bytes for the purpose alignment so that  msg[0] can be aligned to a 4-byte boundary.

There is a good chance that

```
Message_Header_Type obj;
printf("Size : %zu\n",sizeof(obj));
```

would give you 2 as a the result.